# How can I solve this error in nano (couchdb) Express.js

Tags: angularjs, express, nano

> (node:7636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
>       at ServerResponse.header
>    (C:\Users\username\path\Express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\username\path\Express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\username\path\Express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\username\path\Express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
>       at body.rows.forEach (C:\Users\username\path\Express\app.js:41:15)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at db.list.then (C:\Users\username\path\Express\app.js:40:19)
>       at 
>   (node:7636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

Here is the code for the query:

```js
app.get("/api/customers", (req, res, next) =>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    
    db.list({ include_docs: true }).then((body) => {
        body.rows.forEach((doc) => {
          res.send(doc.doc);
        });
      });
  });
```

I want to show data on the html page using angularjs.

Any help I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to send data multiple times inside loop, hence that error. 
Why don't you send whole body data like below:

```
app.get("/api/customers", (req, res, next) =>{

    db.list({ include_docs: true }).then((body) => {
        res.send({data: body.rows});
    }).catch(e => {res.status(500).send({msg: 'Sorry, something went wrong'})});
  });
```

UPDATE 1

To enabled CORS, create a middleware and add it t your app

```
//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain)
```

Comment: After updating the code with your answer I am getting this message in console log

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:800/api/customers. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: I have installed cors in my express REST folder but I am still getting the error message

Comment: Can you share your server-side code on how you enabled CORS?